# ISynchronizeInvoke vs SynchronizationContext vs mainForm.Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a Worker class and a MainForm/UI class. From the UI class I create a new instance of the Worker class in a new background thread. This thread marshals a few updates back to the UI's controls. Since they are in different classes I basically pass the MainForm instance (this) and an appropriate delegate to update the controls, into the worker class' constructor. In the constructor I set the mainForm to an `ISynchronizeInvoke` object (call it _synch) and then, further down in the worker class I do `_synch.Invoke(theDelegate, new object[] { "new value" })`.

That all works fine, but then I realized that it is also possible to do just simply `mainForm.Invoke` (not using the `ISynchronizeInvoke` object). What is the difference between the two?

To make matters worse I read in an article that `ISynchronizeInvoke` is not really needed much anymore, now that `SynchronizationContext` has come a long. I realize that I do not understand what these two are for. Any help with understanding why I should use Invoke on these objects as opposed to directly on the mainForm would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ISynchronizeInvoke is only useful to another library that does *not* have any idea which particular thread is the UI thread or how to properly invoke to code that manipulates the UI.  Never a problem with the Form class, it *is* the UI.  And implements the plumbing that makes ISynchronizeInvoke work.  Sadly WPF broke the contract so it isn't a general-purpose interface anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans. I tried to switch to `SynchronizationContext` as suggested by Sriram, but Send and Post do not accept custom delegates. They take a SendOrPostCallback delegate that only has one parameter (`object`). My current custom delegate has both a value string (the text I want the label to take) and a string lbName, so that the method can identify what label control to update. What do you recommend me doing here? Should i just stick to Form.Invoke? Thanks!

Comment: Using Invoke is wrong 99% of the time.  Very prone to deadlock and races, always use BeginInvoke.  A single object is enough to store *anything*, use small helper classes if necessary.  A lambda is almost always the handy alternative.

Comment: @HansPassant BeginInvoke did not work in my case, as I have several Invokes below each other (to update different labels in a `while(!mre.WaitOne(50))` loop. So if I used BeginInvoke the labels were stuttering, and not updating smoothly. I am not able to give a good technical explanation as to why. On the topic of SynchronizationContext it seems like a bad decision to go for that here, as I would have to create a helper class as mentioned (additional code/complexity), when I do not really get anything in return. Form.Invoke has the same effect as _synch.Send in this case. Would you not agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Winforms, No matter what method you call `Form.Invoke`, `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke`, `SynchronizationContext.Send` you are doing the same thing.

In fact they all internally goes to the same method which is `Control.Invoke`(which implements `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface member).

> What is the difference between the two(Form.Invoke and ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke)?

Nothing, they are pointing to same method `Control.Invoke`.

That said, if you depend on `ISynchronizeInvoke` you'll feel the pain when you're porting the application to another technology (say WPF). `ISynchronizeInvoke` is not supported there. It is the Winforms specific thing. You should always favour `SynchronizationContext` over anything.

`SynchronizationContext` provides the abstraction, whatever the technology may be, you can marshal the call to UI thread(typically not always) via `SynchronizationContext`. If your code depends on `SynchronizationContext` you can port to WPF or Asp.Net easily as they provide  their technology specic implementation of SynchronizationContext.

- Winforms implementation             - WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
- Wpf/Silverlight implementation      - DispatcherSynchronizationContext
- Asp.net implementation              - AspNetSynchronizationContext
- Etc

One disadvantage of `SynchronizationContext` is that it provides no way to get the return value, though you can workaround it via closures, instance members etc.

Further reading: [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! So I will forget about ISynchronizeInvoke. Regarding just using Form.Invoke, the downside is that Form.Invoke would not work if i switched to WPF (even if the controls there had the same name)?

Comment: I am getting this error in the constructor if I try to use SynchronizationContext as the object instead: `Cannot convert source type MainForm to target type SynchronizationContext`. Any idea?

Comment: @Anders You can't use the same control in wpf. You'll use the wpf specific equivalent control. Though you can use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in wpf, that means you need to modify your code. if `SynchronizationContext` was used it will work as it is.

Comment: You can't assign it just like that, you need to use `SynchronizationContext.Current` property after creating the form. Refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can the delegate only have one parameter? with Invoke I used a delegate that had a string value and a label name as string, that got sent back so the UI thread could update its correct control. Now I am getting an error that the `delegate is not assignable to parameter type SendOrPostCallback`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Anders Please take a look at lambda expressions. It will allow you to pass multiple parameters via closures. Or alternatively you can create a class which holds necessary information and use that. Hope that helps, if not please search on the same topic or feel free to ask new question as that's a new question. Future readers will be benefited if they can find it as a new question.